# Blazor Server app does not reflect changes on refresh

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created a Blazor Server project in Visual Studio 2019.
When I run the application and then make a change in .razor file, it doesn't reflect on the page refresh.  Clicking on the fire button in VS, is also not applying the change.

For every change, I need to stop and and run it again.

What should I do to be able to see the changes on page refresh.

**EDIT:**

Hot reload settings in VS

[image]

Also, I'm watching a video tutorial, where the project is Blazor Server and the refresh still works.

Comment: Hot reload on Blazor server is practically useless - it almost always rebuilds the whole project. Blazor WebAssembly is much better. So I suggest you do the UI dev work in webassembly and then port it to Blazor Server after you are done dev/testing.

Comment: @MayurEkbote It's the same with the Wasm project too. While in debug mode, I change a text and do a hard refresh. It doesn't reflect. Am i missing something here.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your hot reload settings? How big is your project?

Comment: @MayurEkbote I have added the snap in the post. Could you pls chk.

Comment: This is XAML hot reload. You need .net hot reload. In VS 2019 it should be somewhere under experimental features. Btw, see if you can update to VS 2022, it is much more stable.